# Is it possible to combine a string and variable as an alias to a table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, variables, alias

I have a table with columns that would (for example) be called 'Financial Year 2022', 'Financial Year 2023' etc...

My aim is to have 'Financial Year ' as the string, and then the year as a variable '@year' and call the columns 'Financial Year @year', 'Financial Year (@year + 1)'

Does anyone know how or even if it can be done?

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL(i.e. construct the SQL as a string and run that) if you want to give columns variable names.

Comment: If I understand you correctly... You're looking for dynamic column names.   SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.   This leaves Dynamic SQL or leave the columns as year1 and year2 and promote the desired column names to the presentation layer.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have a seperate column for each year anyway. Just add a date column to be able to seperate the year/month/decade financial information. Makes everything easier

Comment: That's going to be a really bad design and a nightmare to query. Just unpivot it into separate rows, and have a `Year` column